# How to use setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbardrawertoggle

I have an activity with 2 fragments and drawer. So when i am in fragment i get "Up" icon instead hamburger icon (with the help of setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled) but the action is still the same - navigation_drawer_open/close. So how to get onBackPressed() instead?

And according to this comment i dont know how to handle the Home/Up by myself because of "automatically handle clicks".

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic handling usually only works between activities. Since you are using fragments you may need to handle them manually.

Here's an example on how to handle a back button press.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: // This is the home/back button
                onBackPressed(); // Handle what to do on home/back press
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I did try this,  but in my case looks like onOptionsItemSelected did not fired at all if i click on home\upp button

Answer (score 0):

For do this you must use Custom Toolbar and instead of android menu key use from this library :
[material-menu](https://github.com/balysv/material-menu)

In this library you can change state for arrow and rotate -90 for show Up Icon instead of Burger icon.